# Sign up wit Apple - Firebase - Angular Web JavaScript

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add the Apple Authentication offered by Firebase.

I've created a Apple Developer account and have made the necessary actions on their end.

Below is the code that I use when the apple login button from my Web app is clicked:
It follows this example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple?authuser=0&hl=en#web-version-9

```
    logInApple() {
        const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');
        provider.addScope('email');
        provider.addScope('name');

        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
          .then((result) => {
            debugger;

            // The signed-in user info.
            const user = result.user;

            // Apple credential
            const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
            const idToken = credential.idToken;

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            debugger;
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            const email = error.customData.email;
            // The credential that was used.
            const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);

            // ...
          });
          
        } // logIn()
```

[image]

The `catch` error handler is triggered with the following message:

```
Firebase: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. (auth/operation-not-allowed).
```

But the Apple provider is activated. Picture above.
I've even tried to enable/disable/remove/add it again and doesn't work.

Before this error, the previous error was:

```
Firebase: Unable to establish a connection with the popup. It may have been blocked by the browser.
```

I've also tried to remove/modify the field in Firebase Authentication Provides > Apple > Services ID (not required for Apple) but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.
The configuration of Apple sign in on Firebase was required.
All of the fields were required.

It was confusing because:

1. it says: "Services ID **(not required for Apple)**"
2. You have to click on "OAuth code flow configuration **(optional)**" to open the options

[image]